# Spring JPA Create questions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a "game", it's just to learn, and I'd like to know how would be a good way to create with JPA like a study game, for instance :

I have these classes / tables in main

```
Question : text, description, set<Answer>, difficulty, userWhoCreated, Topic
Topic : name, set<question>
SubTopic : name, set<question>
Answer : text, question (to reference to it)
Quiz : set<question>, name, description
```

But then I'm at the point that I'd like to have like a repository to store all of those questions, so when the user want to study a little bit just get questions from that repository.

The goal of the topic and the subtopic is for the filter out then when user want questions, for instance.

### EXAMPLE

Question : What's a Join?
Topic would be Database
Subtopic would be Joins

Could you guide me how to follow with this?

Example of my question class

```
@Entity(name = "question")
public class Question extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "question_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Question name can not be blank")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_exam_question", nullable = false)
    private Boolean is_exam_question;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Example Answer entity

```
@Entity(name = "answer")
public class Answer extends DateAudit {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "answer_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "answer_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "answer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "answer_to_question")
    @NotBlank(message = "Answer to question name can not be blank")
    private String answer_to_question;

    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;

    @Column(name="type_answer")
    private AnswerType answerType;
}
```

Also I'm seeing that I can not create answer like "TRUE/FALSE", "YES/NO", "Small description","MULTI-CHOICE" how do I deal with it?

Comment: What's your question? Didn't understand.

Comment: How do I structure the scenario? I mean I tried it but I'm stuck now, is the classes/tables well done?

Comment: You need to create a class (entity) for each of those objects that will need to be persisted in the database

Comment: @AlessandroPolverini I edited my question, but I don't know how to deal with the Topic , subtopic and repository stuff

Comment: Your classes seems ok, so what's next?

Comment: The thing is I did not created the Topic and Subtopic because I have no clue to how to do it, also have a problem with the repository stuff and answer check my question I've edited it.

Comment: Some many questions. Ask one question here - not the three you currently have - and  when that is resolved ask the others.

Comment: @AlanHay, ok, sorry so my first question is I did not created the Topic and Subtopic classes, and my answer of a question just accept strings in my case how can I do it clean and maintenable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Topic can be a 'self-referencing' entity i.e. can have an optional parent topic and an optional collection of sub-topics.

Topics can be nested to any level: TopicA > TopicA_1 > Topic_A_1_1 etc.

By writing a recursive function in Topic we can walk the tree and for a Topic at any level in the hierarchy get the questions for that Topic and all its sub-topics.

**Topic:**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class Topic{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Topic> subTopics;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Topic parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic")
    private Set<Question> questions;

    //questions for this exact topic
    public Set<Question> getQuestions(){
        return questions;
    }

    //questions for this topic and all its sub-topics
    public Set<Question> getAllQuestions(){
        return getAllQuestions(this);
    }

    //recursive function to walk the topic tree and get all questions for each sub-topic
    private Set<Question> getAllQuestions(Topic topic){
        Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>(topic.getQuestions());

        for(Topic subTopic : topic.getSubTopics()){
            questions.addAll(getAllQuestions(subTopic));
        )

        return  questions;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "topic_id")
    private Topic topic;
}
```

So with a reference to a topic I can get either its direct questions only or all its questions plus the questions for all its sub-topics (and all their sub-topics.....)

```
Topic topic = topicRepository.findOne(someId);

//only questions directly linked to this topic
Set<Question> questions = topic.getQuestions();

//all questions linked to this topic and its sub-topics to *n* levels.
Set<Question> questions = topic.getAllQuestions();
```

Comment: Nice answer @Alan Hay, I'm afraid because I don't understand how my example of Question would work with your answer, check my question please

Comment: You question appears to be how to get the questions for a topic. If that is not the case then you should make it clear exactly what it is before anyone wastes any more of their time on it.

Comment: I mean how would I create a question like this : (Question)What's a Join?(Topic)Database(Subtopic)Joins

Comment: You give it 1 and only 1 topic as clearly detailed above. A topic itself knows about its (optional) parent so the question itself doesn't doesn't need to redundantly  store the parent topic. `Question q = new Question(); q.setTopic(someTopic);`

Comment: I'm not getting you, could you explain it with other words please?

Comment: A question has a relationship to a topic. A topic has many questions. If that is not clear than I am not sure I can help any further. I would suggest reading up on some basics.

Comment: I got it, yes, but I'm wondering if I have many questions with the subtopic "join" I can get all questions with join filter, or If I want to get all questions of "database"(parent topic) I can get all of them

Comment: GetAllQuestions method is messed up, there's problems with HashSet, void, etc... can you modify it? Maybe you meant : `private Set<Question> getAllQuestions(Topic topic){
        Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>(topic.getQuestions());

        for(Topic subTopic : subTopics){
            questions.addAll(getAllQuestions(subTopic));
        }
        return  questions;
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189139/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-alan-hay).

Comment: Just asked a question on the chat about this