# how to deep recursive parent child relationship in java

Tags: spring-boot

This data set looks like in the following query result, which is the ouput of a very simple TABLE dndclasses; SQL command:

```
id │ parent_id │           name            
════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════════════
  1 │         ¤ │ Warrior
  2 │         ¤ │ Wizard
  3 │         ¤ │ Priest
  4 │         ¤ │ Rogue
  5 │         1 │ Fighter
  6 │         1 │ Paladin
  7 │         1 │ Ranger
  8 │         2 │ Mage
  9 │         2 │ Specialist wizard
 10 │         3 │ Cleric
 11 │         3 │ Druid
 12 │         3 │ Priest of specific mythos
 13 │         4 │ Thief
 14 │         4 │ Bard
 15 │        13 │ Assassin
(15 rows)
```

### output : The result we need now should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Wizard",
        "Sub Classes": ["Mage", "Specialist wizard"]
    }
    {
        "Name": "Priest",
        "Sub Classes": ["Cleric", "Druid", "Priest of specific mythos"]
    }
    {
        "Name": "Warrior",
        "Sub Classes": ["Fighter", "Paladin", "Ranger"]
    }
    {
        "Name": "Rogue",
        "Sub Classes": ["Thief", "Bard"]
    }
    {
        "Name": "Rogue",
        "Sub Classes": {
            "Name": "Thief", "Sub Classes": ["Assassin"]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi, please read those before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you doing this in SQL/JDBC or are you using JPA? For the latter see the answer  here which would solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907237/spring-jpa-create-questions/54909133#54909133. For an SQL based approach you would probably need to use some specific function provided by your RDBMS of choice. e.g. Oracle connect by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319284/sql-recursive-query-on-self-referencing-table-oracle